# Run powershell file after closing program

Tags: powershell

I dont know if this relate to here but there is a way to run powershell file after closing specific program for example, if i close microsoft word automaticly will open a powershell file.
thanks.

Comment: Can you give me more information? Is the application started with powershell?

Comment: You could have a powershell script running in the background, monitoring a certain process, and do stuff when that process is no longer present for instance?

Answer (score 0):

An option?

```
while (Get-Process -Name "powershell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)  {
    Write-Host -Object "Running..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
Start-Process -FilePath "MSG.Exe" -ArgumentList "* Stopped..."
```